# Validate has_many with length in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following model with this validation:

```
class Order
  has_many :rows
  validates :rows, length: { maximum: MAX_ROWS_ORDER }, on: :create
end
```

I am trying to test that when I create an Order I cannot have more than MAX_ROWS_ORDER rows. So, I am trying this:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:order, rows: FactoryGirl.create_list(:row, 100) ).should_not be_valid
```

But is not working, it's actually creating the Order.

How am I supposed to test this?

Comment: You're testing a single line of Rails DSL. You probably shouldn't bother; assume that Rails works.

Comment: I would test your validation. It's not testing Rails, it's testing that the validation is present.